# Uncaught ReferenceError: platform is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, error-handling

Yes so i recently picked up javascript as another language to learn. I was working on a friend's website and we need to keep logs of the platform OS so that we can rate our stats.

I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: platform is not defined at get_platform (eval at  (file:///C:/Users/*****/Desktop/Project/index.html:2:9), :1:191)

Does anyone have any idea on how i could go about fixing this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is my code.

```
function get_platform(os_name) {
var os_str = os_name;
var chk_win = os_str.substr(0, 3);
if (chk_win == "Win")
    platform = "win";
if (chk_win == "Lin")
    platform = "linux";
if (chk_win == "X11")
    platform = "unix";
return platform};
function get_os() {
var OSName = "Unknown";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.3") != -1)
    OSName = "Windows 8.1";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2") != -1)
    OSName = "Windows 8";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1") != -1)
    OSName = "Windows 7";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") != -1)
    OSName = "Windows Vista";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1") != -1)
    OSName = "Windows XP";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.0") != -1)
    OSName = "Windows 2000";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1)
    OSName = "Mac/iOS";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("X11") != -1)
    OSName = "UNIX";
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux") != -1)
    OSName = "Linux";
return OSName};
```

Comment: you platform variable will not be initialized unless it get executed in the if condition ur case might be where it never falls in any condition and while returning it never defined

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ... it looks like the variable platform hasn't been defined properly.

```
function get_platform(os_name) {
  var os_str = os_name;
  var chk_win = os_str.substr(0, 3);
  var platform = "";
  if (chk_win == "Win")
    platform = "win";
  if (chk_win == "Lin")
    platform = "linux";
  if (chk_win == "X11")
    platform = "unix";
  return platform
};
```

Note this line added above; you can define it this way or add a 'default' option:

```
var platform = "";
```